# the title prop of a button must be a string - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

while run on device getting error like this "**the title prop of a button must be a string - react native**"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
Button,
View
} from 'react-native';

export default class sample extends Component {

render() {
return (
    <Button
      style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'green'}}
      styleDisabled={{color: 'red'}}
      onPress={() => this._handlePress()}>
      title="Press Me"
    </Button>
);
}


_handlePress() {
  console.log('Pressed!');
}
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('sample', () => sample);
```

Comment: Typo `**>**title="Press Me"` should be `title="Press Me"**>**`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you have closed the Button tag too early.

```
<Button
  style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'green'}}
  styleDisabled={{color: 'red'}}
  onPress={() => this._handlePress()}> // <-- closed tag here
  title="Press Me"
</Button>
```

Just close the tag after the title attribute

```
<Button
  style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'green'}}
  styleDisabled={{color: 'red'}}
  onPress={() => this._handlePress()}
  title="Press Me"
>
  Press Me
</Button>
```

Comment: Note: if your syntax highlighter doesn't make this error jump to the eye, you could try using a different highlighter or color scheme. This problem is hard to spot on white text, but should be evident with proper coloring

Answer (score 7):

Button name should be written with title keyword

Example :

```
<Button
  style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'green'}}
  styleDisabled={{color: 'red'}}
  onPress={() => this._handlePress()}
  title="Press Me"
>
</Button>
```

> title="Press Me" inside Button tag

Answer (score 5):

Actually, in my case, I was missing the **'title'**
prop. That's why it was showing the error. When I added the **'title'** prop, the error was disappeared. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the **button contains the title attribute**. If it is missing then try to add it else check the closing of the button.

Try to change the button from the below format,

```
<Button
  style={{color: 'white'}}
  onPress={() => this._handleSubmit()}
>
Submit
</Button>
```

to the following format (**correct one**).

```
<Button
  style={{color: 'white'}}
  onPress={() => this._handleSubmit()}
  title="Submit"
/>
```